# how to Call Javascript file in dotnetnuke

Tags: javascript, c#-4.0, dotnetnuke

I am new in dot net nuke so when i am adding java script file on user control its not loading while all other java script is loading even i have tried on both ascx and code behind.so what i have to code to load java script fie
 given below is code

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude("News", ResolveUrl("~/Script/News.js"));
        //  ClientResourceManager.RegisterScript(this.Page, "~/Script/" + "News.js", 101, "DnnPageHeaderProvider");
        //  ClientResourceManager.RegisterScript(this.Page, "~/Script/" + "NewsScript.js", 101, "DnnPageHeaderProvider");//105,  page label js after all global js 
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        this.logException("Error_PageLoad", ex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If this usercontrol is a view in your custom module and the script is in a local folder in your module, the best practice is to use DNN's Client Resource Management API to register your javascript on the page.

So, for example, if your module project looks like this:

```
DesktopModules/[ModuleName]
-view.ascx
-view.ascx.cs
-js/module.js
-css/module.css
```

You can add the following code to the view.ascx.cs:

```
using DotNetNuke.Web.Client.ClientResourceManagement;

protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ClientResourceManager.RegisterStyleSheet(this.Page, base.ControlPath + "css/module.css", 
    DotNetNuke.Web.Client.FileOrder.Css.DefaultPriority);

    ClientResourceManager.RegisterScript(this.Page, base.ControlPath + "js/module.js",
    DotNetNuke.Web.Client.FileOrder.Js.DefaultPriority);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply.. Got it.